# How to split the edge in C++

Tags: c++, model, graph-algorithm, computational-geometry, 3d-model

I've learnt the loop subdivision recently and I implemented some of it by Qt. 
I want to subdivide "the triangle" by calculating the position of the new point, splitting the edge and flip the edge.But it seems that there are some problems about my own "splitEdge()" .

I don't know why.many thanks.

```
// definition.
struct HalfEdge{
    bool old;
    Vertex * origin;
    HalfEdge * pair;
    HalfEdge * prev;
    HalfEdge * next;
    Face * face;
};
struct Vertex{
    bool old;
    QVector3D pos, newPos;
    HalfEdge * edge;
};
struct Face{
    HalfEdge * edge;
};
// the problem splitEgde()
void Mesh::splitEdge(HalfEdge *e){
    HalfEdge * prev = e->prev;
    HalfEdge * next = e->next;
    HalfEdge * p = e->pair;
    Vertex * v = new Vertex();
    v->pos = v->newPos = newVertexPosition[e];
    v->old = false;
    HalfEdge * eNext = new HalfEdge();
    HalfEdge * vOut = new HalfEdge();
    HalfEdge * vIn = new HalfEdge();
    Face * vFace = new Face();
    /******** face A *******/
    // edge
    e->next = eNext;
    eNext->old = false;
    eNext->origin = v;
    eNext->pair = vIn;
    eNext->prev = e;
    eNext->next = prev;
    eNext->face = e->face;
    prev->prev = eNext;
    // vertex
    // face
    e->face->edge = e;
    /******** face A *******/
    /******** face B *******/
    // edge
    vOut->old = true; // !!
    vOut->origin = v;
    vOut->pair = NULL;
    vOut->prev = vIn;
    vOut->next = next;
    vOut->face = vFace;
    next->prev = vOut;
    next->next = vIn;
    next->face = vFace;
    vIn->old = false;
    vIn->origin = prev->origin;
    vIn->pair = eNext;
    vIn->prev = next;
    vIn->next = vOut;
    vIn->face = vFace;
    // vertex
    v->edge = eNext;
    // face
    vFace->edge = vOut;
    /******** face B *******/
    //the rest is updating the data
}
```

And the error:build-Subdivision-Desktop_Qt_5_12_1_MinGW_64_bit-Debug/debug/SubdivisionWithLighting.exe crashed.

Comment: So your program crashes? Where does it crash? What kind of crash? What did you find out by using your debugger so far? Ideally, provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Apart from that, this question doesn't seem to have much to do with Qt at all!?

Comment: Sorry,it's a really big project, so I can't post the whole codes.And the debugger tell me nothing but it crashed.I just set the point then I know it's the part which what I post above 's problem.And I use QT to edit it, so I add the tag

Comment: I'm afraid we won't really be able to help you without an MCVE or at least knowing where exactly it crashes. What debugger are you using? Are you debugging a debug build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already done，it's a stupid mistake.I forgot to deal with the situation that the edge inside the graph.Now I've implemented it perfectly.